# AWS AppSync Encryption Offline

Tags: react-native, encryption, offline, aws-appsync

I have a scenario where I store sensitive data offline.  Is AppSync offline encrypted when using Native iOS, Native Android, and ReactNative (compiled to android and ios)?

Thanks!

Comment: You can store the data in DynamoDB with AppSync and encrypt it there.

Comment: thank you Richard. Form what I understand DynamoDb is only for cloud/online storage.

Comment: @Richard, storing in DynamoDB means you have online connectivity. But what if you are offline and have a mutation that's waiting to execute once you are back online? Mutations are basically text, to be secure, they would need to be encrypted prior to storing in local cache, then once back online decrypted before sending to the back-end. Or better yet, keep it encrypted the whole time until it gets to the back-end, seems like an even safer solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@dnndeveloper

I work with the AppSync SDK team and we currently do not encrypt the data prior to storing it in the local cache in the offline scenario.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It is a bit misleading when AWS says AppSync is hipaa compliant. https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/hipaa-eligible-services-reference/.  Any plans to encrypt offline? Can I use my sqlite store that has encryption?  This is currently what we do for a azure mobile app that provides hooks for you to 'bring your own offline store'

Comment: Does this still hold true for the aws-appsync client?